# How to group a list by value without causing an Attribute Error

Tags: python, tuples, python-itertools

I have a CSV, `OutputA` with format:

```
Position,Category,Name,Team,Points
1,A,James,Team 1,100
2,A,Mark,Team 2,95
3,A,Tom,Team 1,90
```

I am trying to get an output of a CSV which gets the total points for each team, the average points per team and the number of riders.

So output would be:

```
Team,Points,AvgPoints,NumOfRiders
Team1,190,95,2
Team2,95,95,1
```

I have this function to convert each row to a namedtuple:

```
fields = ("Position", "Category", "Name", "Team", "Points")
Results = namedtuple('CategoryResults', fields)

def csv_to_tuple(path):
    with open(path, 'r', errors='ignore') as file:
        reader = csv.reader(file)
        for row in map(Results._make, reader):
            yield row
```

Then this sorts the rows into a sorted list by there club:

```
moutputA = sorted(list(csv_to_tuple("Male/outputA.csv")), key=lambda k: k[3])
```

This returns a list like:

```
[CategoryResults(Position='13', Category='A', Name='Marek', Team='1', Points='48'), CategoryResults(Position='7', Category='A', Name='', Team='1', Points='70')]
```

I am confident that this so far is right although I could be wrong.

I am trying to create a new list of teams with the points (not yet added up).

For example:

```
[Team 1(1,2,3,4,5)]
[Team 2 (6,9,10)]
etc.
```

The idea is that I can find how many unique values of points there are (this equals the number of riders). However, when trying to group the list I have this code:

```
Clubs = []
Club_Points = []
for Names, Club in groupby(moutputA, lambda x: x[3]):
    for Teams in Names:
        Clubs.append(list(Teams))

for Club, Points in groupby(moutputA, lambda x: x[4]):
    for Point in Clubs:
        Club_Points.append(list(Point))

print(Clubs)
```

but this retuns this error:

```
    Teams.append(list(Team))
AttributeError: 'itertools._grouper' object has no attribute 'append'
```

Comment: You are using variable `Teams` as list and in for-loop too, so it is overwritten. Maybe it's typo (should be `Team` without `s`?)

Comment: Thank you, this has solved my error. However, when I run `print(Clubs)1` - see updated code. It prints as `[['T'], ['e'], ['a'], ['m'], ['1']`. Not, `['Team 1']` as I would hope. What is causing this error? How would you fix it?

Comment: A sample of your data would save us time.

Comment: @JustinEzequiel have updated question to include data and intended output

Comment: Here `Clubs.append(list(Teams))` try to make a string and then append

Comment: @AvishkaDambawinna I do not think that is the problem as if I `print(Teams)` the output is:
`T

e

a

m


1` i.e. each letter is a new line, I think this is seeing each letter in a team as it's own `Teams`

Comment: Can you use 3 party libraries like `pandas` or you can use only built-in tools?

Comment: @datapug only built-in libraries

Comment: It is already in the question.
It is this: `[CategoryResults(Position='13', Category='A', Name='Marek', Team='1', Points='48'), CategoryResults(Position='7', Category='A', Name='', Team='1', Points='70')]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `data.csv` contains:

```
Position,Category,Name,Team,Points
1,A,James,Team 1,100
2,A,Mark,Team 2,95
3,A,Tom,Team 1,90
```

Then this script:

```
import csv
from collections import namedtuple
from itertools import groupby
from statistics import mean

fields = ("Position", "Category", "Name", "Team", "Points")
Results = namedtuple('CategoryResults', fields)

def csv_to_tuple(path):
    with open(path, 'r', errors='ignore') as file:
        next(file) # skip header
        reader = csv.reader(file)
        for row in map(Results._make, reader):
            yield row

moutputA = sorted(csv_to_tuple("data.csv"), key=lambda k: k.Team)

out = []
for team, group in groupby(moutputA, lambda x: x.Team):
    group = list(group)
    d = {}
    d['Team'] = team
    d['Points'] = sum(int(i.Points) for i in group)
    d['AvgPoints'] = mean(int(i.Points) for i in group)
    d['NumOfRider'] = len(group)
    out.append(d)


with open('data_out.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    fieldnames = ['Team', 'Points', 'AvgPoints', 'NumOfRider']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)

    writer.writeheader()
    for row in out:
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Produces `data_out.csv`:

```
Team,Points,AvgPoints,NumOfRider
Team 1,190,95,2
Team 2,95,95,1
```

Screenshot from LibreOffice:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here's a start. You should be able to figure out how to get what you want from this.

```py
import csv, io
from collections import namedtuple
from itertools import groupby

data = '''\
Position,Category,Name,Team,Points
1,A,James,Team 1,100
2,A,Mark,Team 2,95
3,A,Tom,Team 1,90
'''

b = io.StringIO(data)
next(b)

fields = ("Position", "Category", "Name", "Team", "Points")
Results = namedtuple('CategoryResults', fields)


def csv_to_tuple(file):
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    for row in map(Results._make, reader):
        yield row


rows = sorted(list(csv_to_tuple(b)), key=lambda k: k[3])

for TeamName, TeamRows in groupby(rows, lambda x: x[3]):
    print(TeamName)
    TeamPoints = [row.Points for row in TeamRows]
    print(TeamPoints)
    print()
```

Answer (score 1):

All of this would be made easier by just using `pandas`. Check out the code below.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv(input_path)

teams = list(set(df['Team'])) # unique list of all the teams
num_teams = len(teams)

points = np.empty(shape=num_teams)
avg_points = np.empty(shape=num_teams)
num_riders = np.empty(shape=num_teams)

for i in range(num_teams):
    # find all rows where the entry in the 'Team' column
    # is the same as teams[i]
    req = df.loc[df['Team'] == teams[i]]
    points[i] = np.sum(req['Points'])
    num_riders[i] = len(req)
    avg_points[i] = point[i]/num_riders[i]

dict_out = {
    'Team':teams,
    'Points':points,
    'AvgPoints':avg_points,
    'NumOfRiders':num_riders
}
df_out = pd.DataFrame(data=dict_out)
df_out.to_csv(output_path)
```